# Unexpected behaviour of RegionFunction in 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I am trying to plot a function defined in a specific parameter space using the `RegionFunction` option in `Plot3D`.

So, this is how I define the region where I want to plot my function

```
Vld[l_, c_] = If[0 < Q3A < 1 && 1 > A > 0 && 1 > B > 0, True,  False]
```

Then, I do

```
A = 1/2; B = 1/2; H = 2/10; G = 1/2;
```

Followed by

```
Plot1 = 
  Plot3D[Q3A, {L, 00, 1}, {c, 0.0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"L", "c", "PlatformUtil"},  
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Vld[x, y]], 
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

When I look at the plot, I should not see any value above 1, but I see a few spikes in the corner.

[image: Plot with spikes]

Am I doing something wrong in the way I am using the region function?

**UPDATE**

Here is a variation of the same problem which is a little trickier to fix

```
Plot1 = 
  Plot3D[PU, {L, 00, 1}, {c, 0.0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"L", "c", "PlatformUtil"},  
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Vld[x, y]], 
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

Where `PU` is also a function of the parameters and Q3A.

When I try `Reduce[Vld[L, c] && PU > 2]`

I get `False`

When I look at the plot, I should not see any value above 1, but I see a few spikes in the corner.

[[image: PU][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjYJ4.png)

Am I doing something wrong in the way I am using the region function?

Comment: does this give what you need `ClearAll[Vld,Q3A ];
Vld[l_, c_, z_] := If[0 < z < 1 && 1 > A > 0 && 1 > B > 0, True, False];
A = 1/2; B = 1/2; H = 2/10; G = 1/2;
Q3A = 10 (L c);
Plot1 = Plot3D[Q3A, {L, 0, 1}, {c, 0.0, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Vld[x, y, z]]]`?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I see that you have added `0 < z < 1 &&` to the condition. Actually what I intend to plot is a function of Q3A which is messy to paste here. I debugged it down to Q3A exceeding the limit. Is there a way to get around this problem where I can't specify a condition on Q3A?

Comment: SreeVathsan, `z` in  the condition `0<z<1` stands for the the value in the third-dimension (the value the first argument of `Plot3D`, i.e. `Q3A` takes).

Comment: Thank you kglr. I got it. What I am trying to do it plot another function of Q3A. There, I cannot do this because the third argument is no longer Q3A.